# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main - how can I fix that?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Causes of 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main Exception in thread “main”'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407250/causes-of-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-main-exception-in-thread-main)

I am using Eclipse.  I deleted everything and left the main function - nothing is working.  Can somebody pls help?

```
package good;

import java.io.*;

public class FiFo {     
    public static void main()
    {
        System.out.println("here");
    }
}    

class FileReader {
    public FileReader(String fileName)
    {
        try {
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This Community Wiki question lists the possible causes of this common problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407250/causes-of-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-main-exception-in-thread-main

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main function should have a signature like:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
   // stuff ...
}
```

You've missed out the String array.  When you run the program it expects to find [a method with this signature](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html), not the empty arg list you have in your sample code.

Comment: In particular, the `String[]` parameter is not optional.

Answer (score 0):

from the java docs:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
>
> The Java VM requires that the class
>   you execute with it have a main method
>   at which to begin execution of your
>   application.

so it's probably the wrong main signature, as stated in the first post

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Run
{
    static BufferedReader nhap = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    public Run()
    {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {   
        int chon;
        System.out.println("1. Nhap Sinh Vien");
        System.out.println("2. Nhap Giao Vien");
        System.out.println("=> Moi ban chon 1 hoac 2 de nhap lieu");
        chon = Integer.parseInt(nhap.readLine());

        switch (chon)
        {   
            case 1:
            {
                System.out.print("So luong sinh vien can nhap vao: ");
                int SoSV = Integer.parseInt(nhap.readLine());
                System.out.print("=> Test  :  " + SoSV );
                SinhVien[] SV = new SinhVien[SoSV];
                int i;
                for (i = 0; i < SV.length; i++);
                {
                    System.out.printf("Nhap thong tin Sinh vien thu %d \n ", i + 1);
                    SV[i] = new SinhVien();
                    AddSV(SV[i]);
                }
            }
            case 2:
            {   
            }
            default: System.out.println("Lua chon cua ban khong co trong danh sach !");
        }   
    }

    public static void AddGV(GiaoVien gv) throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Nhap ma Giao vien: ");
            int ma = Integer.parseInt(nhap.readLine());
            System.out.print("Nhap ho ten giao vien ");
            gv.setHoten(nhap.readLine());
            System.out.print("Nhap tuoi giao vien");
            int tuoi = Integer.parseInt(nhap.readLine());
            System.out.print("Nhap ten khoa giao vien dang day");
            gv.setTenKhoa(nhap.readLine());
            System.out.print("Nhap chuyen nganh giao vien day");
            gv.setChuyenNganh(nhap.readLine());
            System.out.print("Nhap vao Mon giao vien day");
            gv.setMonDay(nhap.readLine());
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {   
            throw new Exception (ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void AddSV(SinhVien sv) throws Exception
    {
        try
        {   
            System.out.println("Nhap ma Sinh vien: ");
            int ma = Integer.parseInt(nhap.readLine());
            System.out.print("Nhap ho ten Sinh vien ");
            sv.setHoten(nhap.readLine());
            System.out.print("Nhap tuoi Sinh vien ");
            int tuoi = Integer.parseInt(nhap.readLine());
            System.out.print("Nhap ten khoa Sinh vien dang hoc");
            sv.setTenKhoa(nhap.readLine());
            System.out.print("Nhap Khoa sinh vien dang hoc");
            sv.setKhoaHoc(nhap.readLine());
            System.out.print("Nhap vao Lop Sinh vien hoc");
            sv.setLop(nhap.readLine());
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception (ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void OutPutSV(SinhVien sv) throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            sv.Tostring();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {   
            throw new Exception(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void OutPuttGV(GiaoVien gv) throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            gv.Tostring();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {   
            throw new Exception (ex.getMessage());
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 public static void main()  // not correct signature for main
```

Comment: That was already answered 4 days ago :)

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Eclipse, you need to make sure that you "Run As" a "Java Application".