# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Causes of 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main Exception in thread “main”'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407250/causes-of-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-main-exception-in-thread-main)

i got this error after i added a method called setConstraints in Generator.class.im free from error when i compiled.
this is the error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: rtg.Generator.setConstra
ints(Ljava/util/ArrayList;)V
        at rtg.DefaultPrompt.main(DefaultPrompt.java:117)

this is the method of setCostraints() in Generator.java

```
private ArrayList<String> constraints_list = new ArrayList<String>();
private boolean constr = false;
public void setConstraints(ArrayList<String> c)
    {
        constraints_list = c;
        constr = true;
    }
```

this the class that is using Generator.class

```
public class DefaultPrompt
{
  public static void main()
  {   
      Generator gen = new Generator();
      gen.setConstraints(constraints_list);
  }
{
```

both classes r in the same package.before added setConstraints, no error.

anyone knows how/why its happen?

Comment: In second code sniplet where does **constraints_list** list comes from?

Comment: You error message has a space in setConstraints

Comment: Are you sure you haven't imported the wrong "Generator" class in your DefaultPrompt?

Comment: your `contraints_list` variable is outside of scope

Comment: Kal, there is no other Generator.class in rtg folder

Comment: Ankit- i forgot constraint_list in 2nd code.its available outside main method.Vasu-there is no space.just copied from prompt and paste here. Kal-there is no other Generator class in rtg package

Comment: This Community Wiki question lists the possible causes of this common problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407250/causes-of-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-main-exception-in-thread-main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the class was not re-compiled after you added the method. Sometimes this happens in some environments. Try deleting all the .class files in the directory and re-compiling again.

Comment: yes,thanks a lot.its works.i deleted all class file and re compile everything.its done..good job Vincent

Answer (score -1):

did u noticed the error clearly u can see the space in the method name

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ***rtg.Generator.setConstra ints(Ljava/util/ArrayList;)V*** at rtg.DefaultPrompt.main(DefaultPrompt.java:117)

Comment: i copied from prompt and paste here without edit it.there is no space between setConstra and ints.in fact, if this happen,i straightly get the error when i compile