# Java Program Error

Tags: java

While I was learning a book, I came across a Java example.  When I compiled it, I had no error.  But when I ran it , it showed:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
```

Since I am beginner in Java, I don't know what it is.

The program is:

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Party
{
public void buildInvite(){
    Frame f = new Frame();
    Label l = new Label("Party at Tim's");

    Button B = new Button("You Bet");
    Button c = new Button("Shoot me");
    Panel p = new Panel();
    p.add(l);
}
}
```

Comment: tip: read a hello world tutorial

Comment: @Bozho, a novice probably need a direct link.

Comment: You simply have to create a main and the invoke new Party().buildInvite();. You may have to call f.setVisible(true) also.

Comment: See the ['Hello World' tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/index.html).

Comment: Read this Community Wiki answer - [Causes of 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main Exception in thread "main"'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407250/causes-of-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-main-exception-in-thread-main)

Comment: BTW - a beginner should not be looking to code GUIs.  Get used to using Java from the command line first.

Answer (score 2):

If you still want to see the execution of this code try this version:

```
class Party{
        public void buildInvite(){
        Frame f = new Frame();
        Label l = new Label("Party at Tim's");
        Button B = new Button("You Bet");
        Button c = new Button("Shoot me");
        Panel p = new Panel();
        p.add(l);
        p.add(B);
        p.add(c);
        f.add(p);
        f.setVisible(true);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new Party().buildInvite();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This code can't be fixed with less work than a complete rewrite.  It doesn't have a main method, cause the frame to show or add the panel to it.  Find a better tutorial.

Comment: *"Find a better tutorial."*  You forgot to mention *"..and it is so old it is teaching AWT".*

Answer (score 1):

All Java programs must have a `main` method. This is what the JVM looks for to start your program.

Comment: So an applet is not a program?  What about a servlet?