# Caused by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: java, jvm

I have this below proram

```
package com;

    import java.io.PrintStream;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.net.URLConnection;

    public class Caller
    {
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        try
        {
          URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/Test/Ravi.jsp");
          connection = url.openConnection();
        }
        catch (Exception ioe)
        {
          URLConnection connection;
          System.err.println("IOException: " + ioe.getMessage());
        }
      }
    }
```

When i am running this i am getting

C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-6.0.33\webapps\Test\WEB-INF\classes>java com.Caller

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/Caller
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.Caller
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: com.Caller.  Program will exit.
```

Comment: probably a silly doubt, but I hope you have made sure that Caller.class exists under C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-6.0.33\webapps\Test\WEB-INF\classes\com ? in case it doesn't, you would have to compile to source using javac. As Jon says in his answer, it is unclear as to why you are trying to run the class from inside tomcat directory

Comment: possible duplicate of [Causes of 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main Exception in thread "main"'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407250/causes-of-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-main-exception-in-thread-main)

Comment: @StephenC: No, it's a different exception, with a different cause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not at all clear why you're trying to run a console app from a Tomcat directory, but basically it can't find your class.

You should probably have a `com` directory under your current directory, and a `Caller.class` file in that directory. If that's not the case, you need to work out how you've compiled the code, and fix it.

My *guess* is that you've just run:

```
javac Caller.java
java com.Caller
```

That will have created the class file in the *current* directory. There are two ways of fixing this. You *could* just use `-d`:

```
javac -d . Caller.java
java com.Caller
```

Or you *could* move the source file into a structure which reflects the package structure, i.e. create a `com` directory yourself:

```
mkdir com
move Caller.java com
javac com\Caller.java
java com.Caller
```

Or even better, you could separate out source from binary files:

```
mkdir src\com
move Caller.java src\com
javac -d bin src\com\Caller.java
java -cp bin com.Caller
```

Answer (score -1):

You must ensure that you add the location of your `.class` file to your classpath, when running the `java` command (so that the execution can find your compiled class).

So, go to the `com` directory, and use:

```
java -cp . Caller
```

Comment: That will fail saying "wrong name: com/Caller" or something similar. The Caller class is declared to be in the com package.

Comment: guess i was just a bit late in updating my answer :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - it's still incorrect now. The OP *shouldn't* do this; it won't work.

Comment: The classes exist , i cam not able to post the picture ,bu still the error persists , did exactly the same .

Comment: @PavanKumar: They may exist, but quite possibly in the wrong place. You need to give us more information (ideally including why you're doing all of this in a *web-app* directory in the first place).

Answer (score -1):

It means that the class in not exist. Pls. try to build your project again and deploy it in web server.

Comment: Well, it may exist but in the wrong place. Personally I wouldn't recommend deploying command line apps in web servers in the first place...

Comment: yup.. you are right. he needs to put it as a right place and proper package structure