# Exception in thread main error

Tags: java, error-handling, logic, program-entry-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Causes of 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main Exception in thread “main”'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407250/causes-of-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-main-exception-in-thread-main)

I'm hoping this is just a simple error here, I've looked up numerous other instantces of people getting the same error message but none of their solutions really seem to apply for me. I was just wondering if you guys could help me find the error in my code. I'm not even sure if it's functional because I can't get it to run, so I suppose it could be a logic error.

When I try to run the following cold I am met with fatal exception error occured. Program will exit.

Eclipse also gives me:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
Exception in thread "main"

Thank you very much for any assistance you can offer!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class JoPuzzle
{

public static Integer main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the number of soliders");
    int soldiers = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the how many soldiers are skipped before the next death");
    int count = input.nextInt();

     List<Integer> soldiersList = new ArrayList<Integer>(soldiers);
      for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {

    soldiersList.add(i);

  }



  int currentIndex = 0;

  while(soldiersList.size() > 1) {

      currentIndex = (currentIndex - 1 + count) % soldiersList.size();

      soldiersList.remove(currentIndex);

  }

  return soldiersList.get(0);

  }   //end main

}//end class
```

Comment: When the program runs, the JVM will check for a method main with signature public static void, which is not present in yours. How is it even starting the execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that to execute any java Program we should have a **main** function. because this is a self callable by JVM.
And the signature of the function must be..

```
public static void main(String[] args){
 }
```

but in your code it's seem like this...

```
public static Integer main(String[] args){
 }
```

so its consider as a different function , so change your main return type..

Answer (score 2):

The signature for main method is 
public static void main(String[] args).

When you run your program the JVM will look for this method to execute. You need to have this method in your code

Comment: Oh wow, yes I changed it initially by trying to get rid of the error on my return soldiersList.get(0) instead of simply printing it. Thanks that should have been obvious. I need sleep -_-

Answer (score 0):

Your program does not contain the main method, change it to

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

If you want to return an Integer object, then define a custom mehod and call that method inside the main method and handle that returned value.

Comment: Or you can exit with a status code to define if the program completed successfully (usually a status of 0) or an error occurred with any other integer you like with System.exit(0);

Answer (score 0):

Java `main()` function doesn't have a return-statement. This line

```
public static Integer main(String[] args)
```

should be

```
public static void main(String [] args)
```

Also since it has no return value, you should delete the `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

[Java's main method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function#Java) should have below signature.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
..
..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this code and tell if it works.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class JoPuzzle
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the number of soliders");
    int soldiers = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the how many soldiers are skipped before the next death");
    int count = input.nextInt();

     List<Integer> soldiersList = new ArrayList<Integer>(soldiers);
      for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {

    soldiersList.add(i);

  }



  int currentIndex = 0;

  while(soldiersList.size() > 1) {

      currentIndex = (currentIndex - 1 + count) % soldiersList.size();

      soldiersList.remove(currentIndex);

  }

 // return soldiersList.get(0);

  System.out.println(soldiersList.get(0));
  }   //end main

}//end class
```