# Why do I get a NoClassDefFoundError Exception in Java?

Tags: java, exception, cmd

I'm trying to run a Java app from the cmd, and I'm getting the following Errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    Could not find the main class: Main.  Program will exit.
```

In the dir you can find:

```
Directory of C:\Java

AVLNode.java
AVLTree.java
Comparator.java
HashTable.java
input1.dat
input2.dat
Main.java
StringComparator.java
```

and I'm Running:

```
java Main input1.dat input2.dat  output1.dat
```

I have Main.Java in the folder and I have:

`public static void main(String[] args)` method on the Main.Java (and some  more functions)

I already read the [answers about this problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407250/causes-of-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-main-exception-in-thread-main) but I think I did everything alright :( so what can be the problem?

Comment: Try using a package next time.

Comment: Have you compiled java texts to classes?

Comment: I do not see any `.class` files. This means that you probably did not compile your code. To compile a Java program, say **p.java**, do `javac p.java`

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you have `Main.class` file in your current directory or not. If it is already there, check your `path` variable in you system environment variables. It should point to `JAVA_HOME\bin`.

Answer (score 1):

as stated in another answer check if `Main.class` is present in current directory

also try `java -cp . Main arg1 arg2`

above line sets classpath to current directory

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that you have compiled your code.

You should be in the directory that contains the Main.class (If you are using eclipse IDE it will be bin/).

If your Main class is in a package you should run your command from the directory that contains the package and your command will be java [package name].Main [arguments]

If you want to run your command from anywhere you can use the -cp option like the following :

```
java -cp [classpath] [package name].Main [arguments]
```

with classpath : path to the directory containing the .class until right before the package

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what the others suggested, check to see if you have any `package` statements in `Main`. If so, you must include it when starting the program.

For example, if you have:

```
package mypackage;

public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] affhf)
    {

    }
}
```

then you must start your program by calling:

`java mypackage.Main input1.dat input2.dat  output1.dat`

This might slip by the compilation process in some situations...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't compiled your code. Try the following:

```
cd Java
javac Main.java
```

This should create the .class files in the Java directory. Then, without changing the directory, try:

```
java Main input1.dat input2.dat output1.dat
```