# Methods without arguments not working on eclipse java

Tags: eclipse, compiler-construction, jvm, java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Causes of 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main Exception in thread “main”'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407250/causes-of-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-main-exception-in-thread-main)

I am having a problem,when I type the following code in eclipse I the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main"

```
public class Hello {

    public void main() {

System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }

}
```

This is the first time I am using eclipse and I wanted to see what it is like. I am using ubuntu 12.04 with java-6-openjdk-i386

Comment: It must be `public static void main(String []args)`

Comment: It is expecting a method public static void main(String args[])

Comment: Check out this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407250/causes-of-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-main-exception-in-thread-main

Comment: It worked,thank you! Strange,it had worked in bluej.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello world!"); 
}
```

Or equivalently:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    System.out.println("Hello world!"); 
}
```