# "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError "

Tags: java, xml, nosuchmethoderror

I was in execution of a java program in order to extract XML files.I received this Run Time Exception when i ran my java program. Please Suggest

During Compilation

This is the compile time error which i got

" GenerateInvoice.java:57: package com.ociweb.xml does not exist
import com.ociweb.xml.Version;
                      ^
GenerateInvoice.java:58: package com.ociweb.xml does not exist
import com.ociweb.xml.WAX;
                      ^
GenerateInvoice.java:69: package com.ociweb.xml does not exist
import com.ociweb.xml.WAX;
                      ^
GenerateInvoice.java:73: cannot resolve symbol
symbol  : class WAX
location: class GenerateInvoice
    WAX waxDoc = null;
    ^
GenerateInvoice.java:453: cannot resolve symbol
symbol  : class WAX
location: class GenerateInvoice
                waxDoc = new WAX("/u01/Output/report/gen_xml/work/" + DIR_NAME + "/" + file_name + "_invoice.xml", Version.V1_0);
                             ^
GenerateInvoice.java:453: cannot resolve symbol
symbol  : variable Version
location: class GenerateInvoice
                waxDoc = new WAX("/u01/Output/report/gen_xml/work/" + DIR_NAME + "/" + file_name + "_invoice.xml", Version.V1_0);
"

Then i added a package "wax14_1.0.4.jar". After Running :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
    java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
        at com.ociweb.xml.XMLUtil.<clinit>(XMLUtil.java:83)
        at com.ociweb.xml.ElementMetadata.buildQualifiedName(ElementMetadata.java:155)
        at com.ociweb.xml.ElementMetadata.<init>(ElementMetadata.java:136)
        at com.ociweb.xml.WAX.start(WAX.java:829)
        at com.ociweb.xml.WAX.start(WAX.java:816)
        at com.ociweb.xml.WAX.start(WAX.java:803)
```

Comment: When i compiled the program i got this compile time error "package com.ociweb.xml does not exist ,import com.ociweb.xml.Version;".. Then i added the jar file "wax14_1.0.4.jar" and compiled successfully.. Then got this error during run time

Comment: What is line 83 of `XMLUtil`?  Did your IDE warn you that there were 'unresolved compilation errors' when you went to run it?

Comment: I was in answering your question and the answer ended with "and so it works" -- if you'd post your faulty code, perhaps I'd post the actual answer. :-)

Comment: Have a look at this community wiki article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407250/causes-of-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-main-exception-in-thread-main

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson When i compiled the program i got this compile time error "package com.ociweb.xml does not exist ,import com.ociweb.xml.Version;".. Then i added the jar file "wax14_1.0.4.jar" and compiled successfully.. Then got this error during run time

Comment: better to share the code you are compiling, it would be easier to answer accurately....

Comment: @tvu - As the primary author of that Q&A, I can assure you that it does not apply in this case.  The OP does not have a problem with the entry point class.  The symptoms are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the doc (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), that method is available since 1.5. Check if you are running an environment < 1.5. If that's the case, you must use Retroweaver, as explained in the project main page (https://code.google.com/p/waxy/).

Comment: Well that explains it. Java 1.4.2 is before Java 1.5.  You need Java 1.5 or later to run that version of `com.ociweb.xml.WAX`.  In fact, you should really upgrade to Java 1.7, because Java 1.5 has been end-of-lifed.