# JOption.showMessageDialog not working

Tags: java, user-interface, joptionpane

So I am new to GUI and I have the following code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class GUItest 

{

    String number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number betch");

    int num_1 = Integer.parseInt(number);

    int product = (num_1*2);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your product is" + product,"Title", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE)
}
```

So my question is how come when I used `JOption` in the first case (I mean `showInputDialog`) it worked with no problems but then when I try to use `showMEssageDialog` the drop down menu wont even appear and many different syntax errors pop up.

Comment: Are you sure you're not missing a main method here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Causes of 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main Exception in thread "main"'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407250/causes-of-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-main-exception-in-thread-main)

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to elaborate on the comment by my friend @YoungDanEn:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class GUItest 

{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        String number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number betch");

        int num_1 = Integer.parseInt(number);

        int product = (num_1*2);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your product is" + product,"Title",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }

}
```

You must have entry point defined, So for above class we needed to define the main method.