# Eclipse error during compilation of a parameterized contructor code

Tags: java, constructor, nosuchmethoderror, parameterized-constructor

When I write a simple parametrised constructor program, it compiles and runs in the command line.

However when it is executed within the Eclipse IDE, I received the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   a_constructor.Test.(II)V at
>   a_constructor.ParametrizedConstructor.main(ParametrizedConstructor.java:15).

**Code :**

```
//write a java program which listed the concept of parameterized constructor
class Test {
    int a,b;
    Test (int x, int y) {
        a=x;
        b=y;
        System.out.println("========================");
        System.out.println("value of a=" +a);
        System.out.println("value of b=" +b);
        System.out.println("========================");
    }
}
public class ParametrizedConstructor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t1=new Test(10,20);
        Test t2=new Test(100,200);
        Test t3=new Test(1000,2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: It does work fine for me

Comment: clean and rerun the program

Comment: No problem here either, clean project or restart Eclipse. When in doubt or suspecting error in Eclipse, you can check your code using online compilers/IDEs, for example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/codingground.htm

Comment: refresh project, then rebuild project.

Comment: Shoud work fine, which JDK and compiler are you using? Like Java 1.8 and Eclipse or IntelliJ etc? Try moving Test in Test.java file (don't forget to make the class public there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ParametrizedConstructor` code is clean and doesn't have any issues.

Try:

- Delete the class files which were generated using the command prompt - If you are using the same location through eclipse to compile the same file.
- Make sure the Java Compiler and Java Build path was matched with the JDK versions.

Alternate Solutions:

- Try placing the code in Eclipse > Java Project > Under default package and run the file.
- We need to have the make sure that the compilation unit is matched to the class name `ParametrizedConstructor.java` (i.e.., public class)

For References - Check also the below links for better understanding:

- Possible [Causes of 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main Exception in thread "main"'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407250/causes-of-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-main-exception-in-thread-main)