# Java: Adding a class function in the main class

Tags: java

I am new to JAVA. I want to create a class and write a function in it. I then want to use that function in the `main` class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class multi_fun {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a, b, c;

        System.out.println("Enter 1st number: ");
        a = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter 2nd number: ");
        b = scan.nextInt();
        Addition obj = new Addition();
        c = obj.add(a,b);
        System.out.println("The sum is "+c);
        scan.close();
    }
}
class Addition{
    public int add (int a, int b)
    {
        return(a+b);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error message, The type Addition is already defined.

Comment: you are doing a good think, your code work fine, what is your problem then?

Comment: add your error message and also some description

Comment: Try to clean Eclipse if you are using it. Your code is working fine

Comment: Here is the error message:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Addition.add(II)I
 at multi_fun.main(multi_fun.java:15)

Comment: You have to pass two parameters. You only have one

Comment: Can you post your whole source code tree? It seems to be problem with your source files, not the code.

Comment: Error:
The type Addition is already defined.
Illegal modifier for the class Addition, only abstract, & final are permitted.

Comment: Please edit your question with the full stack trace error you are ceveiving, what are you doing and such. It's difficult to follow what you are doing just reading the comments.

Comment: A class which is not nested within another class typically goes in its own source file.  Could having `Addition` and `multi_fun` in the same source file be an issue here?

Comment: @VikramSharma without proper description we cannot answer. So add error message(not as a comment).

Comment: @KevinAnderson No it is not a problem here. I've tried it also

Comment: @Blasanka: All the error message are listed in the comment sections.

Comment: errr...add complete error message to the body of question

Comment: And also what is the editor you are using? add it to the question also. No one cannot go through the comments and answer. You have to improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I think according to error message you mentioned in the comments:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   Addition.add(II)I at multi_fun.main(multi_fun.java:15)

It seems that you are putting class `Addition` declaration in the same source file of `multi_fun.java` program.

You should create a java class file called `Addition.java` and put your class code in it:

```
class Addition{
    public int add (int a, int b)
    {
        return(a+b);
    }
}
```

After that it should work without any errors.

**Update**:

You can check this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5407662/5169186) which explain Causes of `'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main Exception in thread “main”'`it would be a useful solution to your problem.

Comment: Do not need to create to Addition.java file in the same class can have multiple class. But make sure all classes are not `public`. And only run main class.

Comment: Yes he can do it in that way. but it's better to separate classes file from the main java program file.

he should know the good practices to write java program in clean and organized way.

also I update my answer and put link to the reasons of this error and the suggested solutions to it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure both the java files are in the same folder.

MultiFun.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MultiFun {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Addition obj = new Addition();

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a, b, c;

        System.out.println("Enter 1st number: ");
        a = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter 2nd number: ");
        b = scan.nextInt();

        c = obj.add(a, b);
        System.out.println("The sum is " + c);
        scan.close();

    }

}
```

Addition.java

```
class Addition {
    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return (a + b);
    }
}
```

run the following commands

```
javac MultiFun.java
java MultiFun
```

Comment: His two classes in the same file.

Comment: do not need to create two java file using one java file this can be done.

Comment: Yeah.. we can do it in both way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are run your program using **Terminal** or **command prompt(cmd)** make sure to **run the class that have main method**(created object from `Addition` class). And also **do not create main methods in both classes** and do not add `public` to `Addition` class.

One last thing: compile and run only the main class(`multi_fun`). Which is,

```
javac multi_fun.java
java multi_fun
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class multi_fun {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a, b, c;

        System.out.println("Enter 1st number: ");
        a = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter 2nd number: ");
        b = scan.nextInt();
        add(a,b);
        System.out.println("The sum is "+c);
        scan.close();

    }

}


public static int add (int a, int b)
{
    return(a+b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is that there was already an other file in the same folder named Addition. So when I wrote a Class with the same name and tried to create an object, it was giving error message, as the parameters where different.

Thank you everyone for your help.