# Main method not found in class jsone.testing, please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args)

Tags: java, jackson

> Error: Main method not found in class jsone.testing, please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args) or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

```
package jsone;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.xpath.operations.String;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

 public class testing {
    @Test
    public static void main(String args[]) {   
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                try {
                    File jsonInputFile = new File("D:\\workspace\\jsone\\car.json");
                    car emp = mapper.readValue(jsonInputFile, car.class);
                    System.out.println(emp);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

---

```
package jsone;

public class car{
    private String colour;

    public String getcolour() {
        return colour;
    }

    public void setcolour(String colour) {
        this.colour = colour;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       sb.append("\n----- Employee Information-----\n");
       sb.append("Colour: " + getcolour() + "\n");
       sb.append("*****************************");
       return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example `String` class comes from `org.apache.xpath.operations.String` package which is wrong. You should use `java.lang.String` class instead. Classes from `java.lang` package are visible in class by default so you have to delete below line:

```
import org.apache.xpath.operations.String;
```

and it should start work. Also, your main method should not be annotated with `@Test` annotation.

Also, please take a look on this question:

1. [Error: Main method not found in class MyClass, please define the main method as…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407250/error-main-method-not-found-in-class-myclass-please-define-the-main-method-as)