# Getting a Main Method not found error and Not sure why

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Im integrating an email sending API and when trying to some java code I am getting "Main method not found in the file, please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args)" although my code includes this.

Here is my code:

```
import com.sendgrid.*;
import java.io.IOException;


public class EmailSender {
 
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Email from = new Email("#####@gmail.com");
    String subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";
    Email to = new Email("$$$$$$@gmail.com");
    Content content = new Content("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with Java");
    Mail mail = new Mail(from, subject, to, content);

    SendGrid sg = new SendGrid("########");
    Request request = new Request();
    try {
      request.setMethod(Method.POST);
      request.setEndpoint("mail/send");
      request.setBody(mail.build());
      Response response = sg.api(request);
      System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
      System.out.println(response.getBody());
      System.out.println(response.getHeaders());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      throw ex;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which Debug configuration you are using? "mainClass" decides which file it will run, ${file} means the currently opened file.

Comment: Most likely you are not *actually* running that class.  Because the `main` method you have shown us there is a valid entry point method.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407250 for what this error message *usually* means.